# Updated_at still being updated even with timestamps to false

Tags: php, laravel, migration

i am migrating my database from prestashop to laravel, so i want to preserve the same data (including creation and update date). But my updated_at column in my store model keeps updating even with timestamps set to false.

```
    $data = request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'iban' => 'sometimes|required|iban',
        'contact' => 'required|array',
        'contact.first_name' => 'required|string',
        'contact.last_name' => 'required|string',
        'contact.email' => 'required|string|unique:users,email',
        'contact.phone' => 'nullable|string',
        'billing_address' => 'sometimes|required|array',
        'billing_address.street_address' => 'sometimes|required|string',
        'billing_address.complement' => 'nullable|string',
        'billing_address.postal_code' => 'sometimes|required|string',
        'billing_address.city' => 'sometimes|required|string',
        'billing_address.country' => 'sometimes|required|string',
        'billing_address.region' => 'nullable|string',
        'created_at' => 'required|date',
        'updated_at' => 'required|date',
    ]);
    $store = app('store')->create(array_merge($data, [
        'status' => Store::STATUS_DRAFT,
        'type' => 'default',
        'company' => '',
        'tos_accepted_at' => null,
    ]));
    if (isset($data['billing_address'])) {
        $billing_address = $store->addresses()->create($data['billing_address']);
        $store->billing_address()->associate($billing_address);
    }
    $contact = $store->users()->create(array_merge($data['contact'], [
        'role' => 'user',
        'locale' => 'fr',
        'country' => optional($store->billing_address)->country ?? 'fr',
        'temporary_password' => 1,
        'password' => '',
    ]));
    $store->contact()->associate($contact);
    $store->timestamps = false;
    $store->save();
```

Comment: You're explicitly populating `created_at` and `updated_at` by having it in the validation `'created_at' => 'required|date', 'updated_at' => 'required|date',`, remove that and it should work.

Comment: @TimLewis It doesnt work, even my created_at column is updated now

Comment: @TimLewis OP expects to override `update_at` which has a prestashop value. But Laravel didn't care.

Comment: @WahyuKristianto exact

Comment: Oooh, sorry, that makes more sense. So you want `created_at` and `updated_at` to be set via `$data` (from `prestashop` values), but then `updated_at` is being set (for example) to today's date? I wonder if `$store->timestamps = false;` doesn't behave well when the values are populated already  Alternatively, you could forego using the model, and instead do `DB::table('stores')->insert(...)`, which, when using `DB::table()` has no concept of Model timestamps, would only populate from `$data`

Comment: @TimLewis I thought about that way of doing it, but my internship supervisor doesnt want me to do it that way :)

Comment: Haha yeah, to be fair, you should use Models when you can, so I understand that. But, the key word there is "when you can". Another thought, move your `$store->timestamps = false;` right after `$store = app('store')->create()`; you might be saving it (which would update `updated_at`) before you actually disable the timestamps, maybe from one of the `->associate()` calls or similar. Also, sidenote, why `app('store')->create()` vs `Store::create()`?

Comment: @TimLewis To keep all the logic to create into one method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm trying to trick Laravel.

```
$store = app('store')->create(array_merge($data, [
    'status' => Store::STATUS_DRAFT,
    'type' => 'default',
    'company' => '',
    'tos_accepted_at' => null,
]));

$store->setCreatedAt($data['created_at']);
$store->setUpdatedAt($data['updated_at']);

$store->save();
```